# CakePHP download file

Tags: cakephp, download

A function like this should download a file:

```
public function downloadFile($id) {
    if (!$this->request->is('post') OR !$this->Benefit->exists($id)) {
        // Alert #1
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Wrong call').' <tt class="pull-right">(C:Benefits, F:sendfile, A:1)</tt>', 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
    } else {
        $this->Benefit->id = $id;
        $benefit = $this->Benefit->read();
        $dfile = APP.'webroot'.DS.'files'.DS.'attachments'.DS.$benefit['Benefit']['file']; //read existing filename
        $this->response->file(
                              $dfile,
                              array(
                                    'download' => true,
                                    'name' => 'Benefit_'.$id
                                    )
                              );
        return $this->response;

    }
}
```

Now I get an error which says:

Fatal Error
Error: Class 'File' not found
File: /home/dateyour/www/www.example.com/lib/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php
Line: 1348

I'm sure the path and the file exists. The system is able to upload a file with this parameters and I see the file there in the FTP. But when it comes to download, I get this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Either the `File` class really doesn't exist, or you have defined a class named `File` somewhere else in your code, which conflicts with the core class.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I hat a Component called FilehandlerComponent in my environment. I don't use it anymore and deleted it. Now everything works ok! Thanks again to ndm!

Comment: Not directly related: You are missing a redirect after `$this->Session->setFlash(BadCall)` by the way. Better yet: Throw a NotFoundException() here instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its class not found, not file not found.

Guess is you have not included the relevant packages.

http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-File.html